# Backup Chrome synced data (accounts/passwords)

Tags: google-chrome, synchronization, backup, password-recovery

Today I realized I lost 2+ years of web account/password data that was [synced](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139&topic=1693469&ctx=topic) across all of my Chrome instances (iOS, Win7, total of 4 computers). My bookmarks were OK. It's [happened](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/iLpzO8OC2wM) to a few people over the years, <del>with not much explanation</del> [at least one explanation](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/iTl_7DgUpkc/NW2kc7mc7c0J) about how to avoid it (probably the data gets corrupted). So I'm wondering how can I back up this data (offline or otherwise).

**Edit**: Google has [restored the data for me and others](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/Q1XEypVdDBo/ckXiP3vPrhQJ). As far as I know, it's a *gracious favor* for them to do that (no guarantees about the quality of this data, etc.). Even more reason to be able to back this up ourselves.

**Note for those who are voting to close this question because it's not for Web Apps**: I posted here because the password data is stored in the cloud, on Google's servers, in a Google Account. The password data is not *local* to a browser.

Comment: The data may be stored in the cloud, but that doesn't (necessarily) make this a Web Apps question.

Comment: That said, have you had a look at [the Data Liberation Front](http://www.dataliberation.org)?

Comment: @AlEverett Thanks. Synced data export/import is a [suggestion](http://goo.gl/mod/EQ4L) in their Google moderator database.

Comment: I've asked similar question: [How secure are the passwords stored at Google Passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/96011/11825)

Comment: @Fuhrmanator The data takeout ale pointed to contains a Chrome part, that has `SyncSettings` - maybe that's it (I don't know since when it's there)